# How to disable fullscreen view with cordova.inAppBrower

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, fullscreen

I'm working with cordova/android and I'm using cordova.inAppBrowser to open a new page. I'm searching a way to disable "fullscreen mode"

I must use the option "_blank" because with the option "_self", I'm loosing the objet "cordova_iab".

```
app.inAppBrowser  = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(domain, "_blank", 
"location=no");
app.inAppBrowser.addEventListener('message', (x) => {
  if (x.data.action=="exit") app.inAppBrowser.close()
});
```

If somebody can help me...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Slayes! Please provide more details to your question description. Do you want to turn full screen off in the whole app or only for that page?

Comment: You should consider reading the StackOverflow publishing guide lines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask